# Software that put watermark in background of PDF

Tags: gratis, pdf, cross-platform, digital-watermarking

I need a software for PDF books that I have on my computer to make me able to:

1. Put my name in the background of each page of my PDF books
2. Put an image of my choice in background
3. Image and writing be misty such that I can read words
4. I can see the watermarks when I print a page

Requirements:

- Free (gratis) software.
- Desktop software, not a webapp. I have both Linux and Windows laptop and computers, so I need a cross platform solution.
- Does not solicit me with popups or ads.

Comment: I'm guessing you're looking for a batch tool, rather than adding the setting to each page individually? Thus, allowing you to select the pdf and it would automatically apply the settings of your choice to the entire pdf, probably excluding the first and last page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a Dysprosium Software Suite [here](http://www.messiahpsychoanalyst.org/Documents/Downloads.html#part4). They call it "Watermark" hence, I edited my post.

It puts photographs and texts with adjustable size and directions in different place.

[image]

and one test result

[image]

I could use it to convert my pictures to PDF too.

Answer (score 1):

The [PDFtk PDF toolkit](http://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/) has, amongst many other features, adding watermarks, there are free and cheap versions both of which offer watermarks, it is cross platform and there is a command line interface so you can add the same watermark to multiple files in a single operation or you can use a batch script to add your standard watermark on demand.

[image: Screenshot of PDFtk Free]

Note that adding watermarks is command line only in the free edition.

*I do not work for or on PDFtk.*